# Application of vorticity tendency equation

Tags: meteorology, atmospheric-circulation, mesoscale-meteorology, dynamics

I have a question about the dynamics of westward propagating vortices. 
In meteorology, the vorticity tendency is often used to explain the westward propagation of vortices (cyclonic circulation).

A good paper that utilizes this is as follows:
https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/JCLI-D-14-00170.1

"Development and Formation Mechanism of the Southeast Asian Winter Heavy Rainfall Events around the South China Sea. Part I: Formation and Propagation of Cold Surge Vortex" by Chen et al. (2015).

This paper used the vorticity tendecy equation at 925hPa.However, I am wondering if it is correct to apply this at this level. Should this be more appropriate at 850hPa or higher levels, where terrain effects are minimal especially over the maritime continent?

Comment: In the tropics generally 925 to 700 hPa surfaces are of interest. So you can calculate vorticity tendency over those layers

Comment: I am sure you are familiar with the Borneo vortex. So the 850 hPa - is appropriate https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/26107977.pdf

Comment: hi @gansub..indeed I am familiar with the borneo vortex. Do you know any reference that I can read about the proper layer where to apply the vorticity budget in general? i have seen many papers using this at 925 and 850hPa. One japanese professor here said that this should be applied in the free atmosphere (850hPa or higher) but he just said that this is because of the dynamics. Still, I want to prove that even at 925hPa this should be applicable.

Comment: In general top of PBL in tropics.